# Customization of Converse.js

Tags: angular, converse.js

Can I use Converse.js in an angular 4 application. If yes, then how?

Can I customize it to build an angular 4 app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely integrate converse.js into Angular.

I recently did it for Angular2, but the principles are similar for Angular4.

I documented my findings here:
https://conversejs.org/docs/html/other_frameworks.html#angular-js

In short, you want to create a service which wraps converse.js and exposes its API.